# javascript get selected radiobutton value that is in repeater?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, radio-button, repeater

aspx script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".div_soru").hide();
        $(".div_soru").first().show();
        $(".onceki").click(function() {
            if ($(this).closest(".div_soru").prev(".div_soru").html() != null) {
                $(this).closest(".div_soru").hide();
                $(this).closest(".div_soru").prev().show();
                $(".bitir").hide();
                $(".sonraki").show();
            }
        });
        $(".sonraki").click(function() {
            if ($(this).closest(".div_soru").next(".div_soru").html() != null) {
                $(this).closest(".div_soru").hide();
                $(this).closest(".div_soru").next().show();
                if ($(this).closest(".div_soru").next().next().html() == null) {
                    $(".bitir").show();
                    $(".sonraki").hide();
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

and aspx:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater_sorular" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="Repeater_sorular_OnItemDataBound"
            OnItemCommand="Repeater_sorular_ItemCommand">
    <HeaderTemplate>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
         <div class="div_soru">
             <div class="div_soru_wrapper">
                 <div style="font-weight: bolder; padding: 5px;">
                    (<%#(((RepeaterItem)Container).ItemIndex+1).ToString() %>
                    /
                    <%# Eval("SoruSayisi")%>)
                    <%#Eval("Subject")%>
                 </div>
                 <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList_secenekler" runat="server" Visible='<%# Eval("TypeId").ToString() == "2" %>'
                    DataSource='<%#Eval("Secenekler")%>' DataTextField="OptionName" DataValueField="OptionId">
                 </asp:RadioButtonList>
                 <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList_secenekler" runat="server" Visible='<%# Eval("TypeId").ToString() == "1" %>'
                    DataSource='<%#Eval("Secenekler")%>' DataTextField="OptionName" DataValueField="OptionId">
                 </asp:CheckBoxList>
              </div>
              <div class="div_nav_buttons">
                  <table>
                      <tr>
                            <td id="onceki" class="onceki">
                                <img src="../Img/adminicons/geri.gif" />
                            </td>
                            <td id="sonraki" class="sonraki">
                                <img src="../Img/adminicons/ileri.gif" />
                            </td>
                            <td id="bitir" class="bitir">
                                <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton_kaydet" runat="server" CommandName="kaydet" ImageUrl="~/Img/adminicons/kaydet.gif"
                                        CommandArgument='<%# Container.ItemIndex %>' OnClientClick="return confirm('Anketi kaydetmek istediğinize emin misiniz?');" />
                            </td>
                      </tr>
                 </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

This script hide radio groups. And I show them one by one with using next and prev button. 
I want to show an error message if a radio in one of radio gruop is not select. How can I current radio group selected value.

I try this but this is getting radio value from the first radio group.

```
var selectedRadios = $(".div_soru_wrapper input:radio:checked").val();
```

I think I cant explain clearly. I hope you understand what I want to do  :) 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check if there is a checked radio button in the currently visible group, the [:visible](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) selector can help you:

```
if ($(".div_soru_wrapper:visible input:radio:checked").length) {
    // There is a checked radio button in the currently visible group.
} else {
    // There is no checked radio button in the currently visible group.
}
```

Comment: it works. I want to ask anotker question. There are checkboxs in some rows in repeater how can check this. thanks

Comment: @Ali, you could use the `:check` selector instead of `:radio`.

Comment: but I dont know which one is checkbox or radio I get them dynamicly.

Comment: @Ali, in that case, you can use a multiple selector. Something like `$(".div_soru_wrapper:visible").find("input:checkbox:checked, input:radio:checked")`.